# Postgres Column with Value Showing Up as Nil in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, date

I have a date column in my Postgres database that when querying the DB directly it appears to be populated (and in the correct format), but when trying to access that attribute in the Rails console or a view it returns nil. Any ideas?!

```
DealArticle Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "deal_articles".* FROM "deal_articles" WHERE "deal_articles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 83]]
=> #<DealArticle id: 83, url: "http://www.finsmes.com/2015/09/stepjockey-raises-60...", raw_article_html: "StepJockey Raises £600K\n\r\n\t\tStepJockey Ltd, a Londo...", source: nil, article_date: "2012-02-04", article_title: "StepJockey Raises £600K", capital_raise_flag: false, buyout_flag: false, capital_raise_amount: nil, buyout_amount: nil, portfolio_company_id: nil, created_at: "2015-09-16 18:30:22", updated_at: "2015-12-05 22:51:58">
```

You can see article_date has a value of "2012-02-04"

However, when I try to access the article_date attribute

```
da.article_date
```

it returns nil.

All other attributes are working properly

Here is the model code:

```
class DealArticle < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :url, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :article_title, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end
```

Using PG gem pg (0.17.1)

Rails 4.0.3

PostgreSQL 9.3.3 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn), 64-bit

Comment: Have you tried adding validates_presence_of :article_date and creating a new one? Looks like its entirely possible to have a nil value in that column. Doesn't explain why the app isn't showing the existing value, but might help. Also, are you sure you're viewing the object with the same in both the app and when querying directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I stupidly had an instance method in my model (a garbage method I was going to do something with before deciding to make a DB column instead) with the same name as the attribute in question, so when calling the attribute it returned nil.